# PDO Error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting the error **Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens** when executing the following code:

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        project_id, 
        product_name,
        product_description,
        imagelg_url,
        product_url, 
        amazon_price,
        your_price,
        review_value,
        coupon 
    FROM project 
    WHERE
        project_id = :id
"; 

$update = " 
    UPDATE project
    SET  
        product_name = :productname, 
        product_description = :productdescription,
        imagelg_url = :imagelgurl,
        product_url = :producturl,
        amazon_price = :amazonprice,
        your_price = :yourprice, 
        review_value = :reviewvalue,
        coupon = :coupon
    WHERE
        project_id = :id
";

// Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query. 
//
$query_params = array(
    ':productname' => $_POST['productname'],
    ':productdescription' => $_POST['productdescription'], 
    ':imagelgurl' => $_POST['imagelgurl'], 
    ':producturl' => $_POST['producturl'],
    ':amazonprice' => $_POST['amazonprice'],
    ':yourprice' => $_POST['yourprice'],
    ':reviewvalue' => $_POST['reviewvalue'],
    ':coupon' => $_POST['coupon']  
); 

try 
{ 
    // These statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $uproject = $db->prepare($update); 
    $uproject->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $up = $uproject->execute($query_params);

}
```

I'm assigning `$id` in the following code:

```
$path_parts = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$id = array_pop($path_parts);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `$uproject->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` line, and instead define it in your `$query_params` like the rest? It's potentially not liking the mixing of bindParam and execute vars.

Comment: Something like ':id' => $id?

Comment: Yep, remembering to add a comma if required.

Comment: Taking a look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php will help you understand better what to do well.

Comment: The above worked, but it looks like I'm using the wrong code for what I'm trying to do, which is update the data after a form has been submitted. It's updating it the second the page loads.

Comment: Then you should wrap the entire block in an `if else` block to only run when the form has been submitted, either by checking the data is there, or checking the submit button has been clicked depending on your implementation of the form.

Comment: You're exactly right, going to do that now. Thanks Jon and Omni for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving the **invalid parameter number** error because you are using `bindParam()` and passing an array into `execute()`. Passing any array to `execute()` will erase and replace any previous bindings.

You need to bind your data through `bindParam()` or `execute()`, but not through both.

To solve this problem, change your `$query_params` assignment to the following:

```
$query_params = array(
    ':id' => $id,
    ':productname' => $_POST['productname'],
    ':productdescription' => $_POST['productdescription'], 
    ':imagelgurl' => $_POST['imagelgurl'], 
    ':producturl' => $_POST['producturl'],
    ':amazonprice' => $_POST['amazonprice'],
    ':yourprice' => $_POST['yourprice'],
    ':reviewvalue' => $_POST['reviewvalue'],
    ':coupon' => $_POST['coupon']  
);
```

Then change your update query to the following:

```
$update = " 
    UPDATE project
    SET  
        id = :id,
        product_name = :productname, 
        product_description = :productdescription,
        imagelg_url = :imagelgurl,
        product_url = :producturl,
        amazon_price = :amazonprice,
        your_price = :yourprice, 
        review_value = :reviewvalue,
        coupon = :coupon
    WHERE
        project_id = :id
";
```

Finally, remove this line from the PDO setup of the update query:

```
$uproject->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Finally figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: Is it required to add ' '  around the new data I'm trying to update? For example, in my sql query... product_name = ':productname', I've tried running this query with my form and it's not updating. and when I put the query into phpmyadmin and run it it gives me mysql errors. After adding '' it worked in mysql, but not working in php.. I'm a little confused.